# Can we run multiple tags in Cypress-Cucumber?

Tags: cucumber, cypress

I want to run test cases having tags @a or @b.

In package.json under scripts, I have provided "test": "cypress run -e TAGS=@a or @b", but it's not working for me.

Is there any way to run multiple tags in Cypress-Cucumber?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: I gave an answer to a very similar question here: [Cucumber scenario with multiple tags does not execute in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70538916/cucumber-scenario-with-multiple-tags-does-not-execute-in-cypress/75549650#75549650)

Answer (score 3):

you can try passing like this "test": "cypress run -e TAGS="'@a or @b'"

Comment: When I store the above command under scripts and execute it is not taking the mentioned tag. Instead it executes everything

Example: cypress run: cypress run -e TAGS="'@a or @b'

Comment: Sorry i have tried this, but it is not picking the `regression-part2 ` tests ...
CYPRESS_baseUrl=my_URL_here npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@regression-part1 or @regression-part2 and not @ignore' GLOB='cypress/integration/**/*.feature' --headless --browser chrome

Comment: Hi @soccerway,

I do not know why, but it works from left to right. So, instead of:

`npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@regression-part1 or @regression-part2 and not @ignore'  `


try the other way round:

`npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='not @ignore and (@regression-part1 or @regression-part2)' `

You can probably remove the parenthesis, but with them it looks more readable.

Answer (score 0):

In scripts from package.json you should only write this:

"test": "cypress run -e"

Nothing else.

And then, when calling this script from the command line, you provide all tagnames you want to run:

npm run test TAGS="@a or @b"