# Cucumber scenario with multiple tags does not execute in Cypress

Tags: cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have multiple tags for a scenario and trying to execute the scenario with Cypress run -env TAGS command and it is not working using Cypress-Cucumber-Preprocess.

@Tag1 @Tag2 @Tag3
Scenario : First Scenario

@Tag1 @Tag2 @Tag3 @Tag4
Scenario : Second Scenario

cypress run -e TAGS='@Tag4' - not working

Both the scenarios will open in testrunner and the test runner freezes.

Comment: Maybe you can add a scenario as an example to improve your question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `cypress run` you should use the built-in `cypress-tags run` command like:

```
cypress-tags run -e TAGS=\"@Tag1 and not @Tag4\" --browser chrome --headless
```

This allows you to run only scenarios with certain tags or explicitly not to run specific tags.

Comment: I tried this.. it is filtering the feature files but not the scenarios. Also, in the test runners scenarios which are not matched with the tags are trying to execute and freezes

Comment: Maybe you could check the examples in this official repo, these at least work on my end: https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-example

Comment: In case those are not working for you as well, could you maybe add the cypress and cucumber preprocessor versions your are using.

Comment: "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.0.1"    "cypress": "^9.2.0",

Comment: @SebastianoVierk, is there a possibility to run cypress scenarios depending by a condition? For example taking into account a feature flag.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples of what has worked for me. I'm tagging individual scenarios.

This will execute only those scenarios tagged @smoke1

```
npx cypress run  -e 'TAGS=@smoke and not @smoke1'
```

These will run scenarios tagged @smoke or @smoke2, but ignore @smoke1

```
npx cypress run  -e 'TAGS= not @smoke1 and (@smoke or @smoke2)'
npx cypress run  -e 'TAGS=(@smoke or @smoke2) and not @smoke1'
```

These will run scenarios tagged @smoke or @smoke2, but ignore @smoke1 or @smoke3

```
npx cypress run  -e 'TAGS=(@smoke or @smoke2) and (not @smoke1 or @smoke3)'
```

Answer (score -1):

Running scripts based on the configuration in your package.json file, if you want to run only the scenarios with specific tags (omitting the others), you can do it in this way:

```
"cy:run": "cypress run --env TAGS=\"@runnig\" --browser chrome --headed"
```

If you want to skip all the scenarios with specific tags, you can do it in this way:

```
"cy:run": "cypress run --env TAGS=\"not @skip\" --browser chrome --headed"
```

In your feature file, this would look like this:

```
@runnig
Scenario: 1. Add an asset indicating an existing asset name
    Given I go to the sales tab
    ...


@skip
Scenario: 2. Add an asset indicating an existing asset name
    Given I go to the billing tab
    ...
```